# Best Practice Validation for Long Form with Disabled Submit Button

Tags: validation, required-fields, long-forms

Hi and thanks in advance for your help. I'm working on a form that was built using Angular 2. By default, the submit button is disabled until all required fields are complete. The form is long and contains text boxes at the top that use inline validation - no problem there.

There are a series of checkboxes at the bottom without inline validation, only a red asterisk by each. Inline validation on these checkboxes would be awkward because the only way I can figure out to trigger them would be to put focus on the next checkbox. There is no control after the last checkbox so nothing to trigger inline validation.

The submit button is on the top of the form and it is disabled by default so that submitting the form isn't possible without all required fields set. so there is a good chance that users will not click the button to fire validations.

Should I change the form so that the submit button is active upon page load so that there is some way to fire validation? Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated as well. Thanks again.

Comment: [https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/disabled-submit-button-on-form-vs-allow-submit-then-show-errors?rq=1](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/disabled-submit-button-on-form-vs-allow-submit-then-show-errors?rq=1) Great answers here about your question.

Comment: The button should be the last control in the flow of the form. If that concerns you look at this question and answer: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/108090/36883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the Submit button disabled makes the user think:

### Something is wrong

But it doesn't really tell them what. Also, they won't be able to figure out if there's an issue with their entry, or with the system, or with the internet.

**It's too vague**

Validation should always be done *on action*. Like:

- When the user moves to the next input field
- When the user hits the **Submit** button

This helps the user understand what went wrong and it also feels intuitive.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I completely agree. Fishing around for a way to make the submit button activate is beyond annoying so that will be the first thing I suggest fixing. Unfortunately our entire app uses that setup but I will be persuasive :). Thank you so much again!